# Does OS X or Xcode have applications to manage cheat sheet/commands list?

Tags: macos, applications, xcode

I'm learning coding on OS X, as I'm a beginner, I have to read cheat sheets and I have bunch of files like that, Git commands, Ubuntu Server commands, Node.js modules command and so on.

Today I saw my friend using Cloud9, it's Cloud IDE, it has a small area called "Commands" where he can search and read tiny description about it, also keyboard shortcut.

I know that feature is so specific to Cloud9, but do we have similar functionality in some app on OS X, where I can create and store my usually cheatsheets? I don't need 100% exactly the same, just same same is ok.

[image]

---

**Update:**
I'm going to write my own app, I will let you know if I can archive anything.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash).

> Dash is an API Documentation Browser and Code Snippet Manager. Dash stores snippets of code and instantly searches offline documentation sets for 150+ APIs ... You can even generate your own docsets or request docsets to be included.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. The idea is really close to what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I use [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) which pops up a window if you press the Command key long enough and displays all currently available keyboard shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea of this app, but it is not what I'm looking for. Example, I'm using Terminal in OS X, and I want to check what is the command to copy files from this folder to another folder in Ubuntu server that I'm working over ssh.

Comment: @SangĐặng just google `bash cheat sheet` or `shell cheat sheet` and you’ll find numerous examples of what you’re looking for. I use one regularly (can’t find the original web source, but I have the single page .pdf). An application is overkill, unless you want it to check the syntax of a particular command…[Text Mate](http://macromates.com) is a great one.

Comment: Please read the question above, dear my friend. I know how to find it. I have tons of cheatsheets in my computer and I WANT A BETTER WAY to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the terminal command 'apropos' could be of use.

For example... 'apropos remote' should show commands for carrying out remote operations.

Answer (score 0):

For applications in OS X, you can search for functions and keyboard shortcuts through an application's "Help" menu. This is similar to Cloud9's commands menu.

[image: Demonstration of the feature mentioned above.]

Comment: I usually like to create my own list on notepad or such since you're on OsX and leave it open for easy reference.

Comment: @Gmenfan83, I have a huge collection on my Evernote, and it works. I just want to manage it better.

Answer (score 0):

> cheat allows you to create and view interactive cheatsheets on the command-line. It was designed to help remind *nix system administrators of options for commands that they use frequently, but not frequently enough to remember.

https://github.com/chrisallenlane/cheat

They also have a wiki page listing similar projects.